# Tabulator: I am using validation mode manual but I want to block on cell if not valid

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using `Tabulator` with validation mode `Manual` or `Highlight`. But at the same time I am also interested in the blocking functionality. But for some reasons, I don't want to check for all `Validators` on specific row editing, that's why I am using highlight or manual mode.

So my question is how can I block user when `ValidationFailed` is called on the same cell (with some conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Reverting the Value

Youif you want to revert the value, could use a mix of the ***getOldValue** and **setValue*** function on the cell component passed into the ***validationFailed*** callback to retrieve the old value of the cell and set it back.

You would then probably want to call the ***clearValidation** function on the cell to clear the invalid flag now that the value has been reset.

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    validationFailed:function(cell, value, validators){
        cell.setValue(cell.getOldValue());
        cell.clearValidation();
    },
});
```

#### Re-triggering the Edit

If you want to keep the user on the cell to keep on editing then you should call the ***edit***function on the cell component

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    validationFailed:function(cell, value, validators){
        setTimeout(() => { //give the edit time to finish before retriggering
            cell.edit(); //retrigger the edit
        }, 100)
    },
});
```

#### Blocking Validation Mode

Im assuming that you want to take this approach because you want to flag some columns as invalid without blocking the edit, and some that you do want to block. If you want to block all invalid edits then you should just use the ***blocking*** validation mode:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    validationMode:"highlight", //highlight cells with validation errors but dont stop the edit
});
```

Comment: Hey Oli, somehow the "Re-triggering the Edit" is not working at my end.. may be because I have my callbacks for `cellEdited` and `cellEditCancelled` .. is there any other work  around ?

Comment: i have updated the example, there needed to be a timeout to give the initial edit time to finished before retriggering it.

Comment: I feel that this mixed approach you are proposing could result in a confusing and poor user experience to have difference cells validate in different ways. you either want them to always block or always highlight, which the default "blocking" mode functionality provides for, without the need for this extra callback usage

Comment: Yep.. it's bad idea.. I have created my custom validator for those fields.. Thanks